# Decoding URL character string vector in R

Tags: r, url, decode

Suppose you have an atomic vector containing URL encoded character strings.

For example:

```
urlencoded<-c("im%20looking%20for%20uncle","im%20looking%20for%20sister")
```

Is there any way to decode every element in the vector, returning a vector of the same length with regular text?

In other words, the output should be:

```
c("im looking for uncle","im looking for sister")
```

URLdecode in base R doesn't vectorize and it's slow. There are lots of utilities outside of R that quickly decode URL encoded character strings, but I can't find any good utility in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply a function to a vector with `sapply`. It will return the result vector:

```
> urlencoded <- c("im%20looking%20for%20uncle", "im%20looking%20for%20sister")
> sapply(urlencoded, URLdecode, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
[1] "im looking for uncle"  "im looking for sister"
```

Answer (score 2):

For those who don't yet know, there's `urltools` package that has the vectorized `url_decode` and `url_encode`:

```
library(urltools)

urlencoded <- c("im%20looking%20for%20uncle","im%20looking%20for%20sister")
url_decode(urlencoded)
# [1] "im looking for uncle"  "im looking for sister"

url_encode(c("im looking for uncle", "im looking for sister"))
# [1] "im%20looking%20for%20uncle"  "im%20looking%20for%20sister"
```